# Fastest way to match data between 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, parsing, search, match, autoit

I have 2 arrays:

- `$r01` has 8,000 rows (single column list of iMDB ID's).
- `$info01` has 44,000 rows (complete movie details including iMDB ID's).

I need to find all records from first array that are in second array. I'm using 2 `For` loops:

```
For $i = 0 to UBound($r01)-1 ; first array
   For $j = 0 to UBound($info01)-1 ; second array
      if StringInStr($info01[$j], 'tt' & $r01[$i])>0 Then  ; search ID - I will add 'tt' to original array, to shave off a few seconds of processing
           _ArrayAdd($found, $all[$j] & @TAB & $r01[$i])   ; add match to $found array
           exitloop     ; exit loop, I do not need duplicate results (yes, they are possible)
      endif
   Next
Next
```

Processing (i7 7700k, 16Gb RAM) takes hours.

Comment: Do you happen to have the arrays as files? `cmd` command `findstr /G:r01.csv info01.csv > found.csv` should be as fast as you can get it. Although it will list duplicates too (which `_ArrayUnique` should be able to solve). (Try it, even if it's only to have a reference for the possible speed)

Comment: First array is file.
Second array is multiple files: 40.000 files, divided into 14 folders and many sub-folders.
I'm not sure it helps me a lot.

Comment: `findstr /S /G:r01.csv info*.csv > found.csv` maybe?

Comment: LOL, holy cr_p! How the h_ll is it that fast?!
Finished processing in like 2 minutes (using HDD, I'll copy them to SSD for a quick test).
I just need to add 'tt' to list of IDs (first array/file) and parse the output and that's it.

Comment: It was too good to be true. It works with one folder (around 3500 files / second array). But when I run it with all files (44000 records) = FINDSTR: Out of memory - error afetr 1-2 seconds / about 10-11 results. Maybe I can run with one single ID. LOL, nope, same error: findstr /L /S tt11219014 "d:\folder\info.txt"

Comment: Hmm. Try `type D:\folder\info.txt | findstr /G:r01.csv` first, then `(for %i in ("F:\irst\folder" "S:\econd\folder" ...) do type "%~i\info*.txt | findstr /G:r01.csv) >found.csv

Comment: This powershell command works, pretty fast (copied all 44000 files to SSD), for one single ID (so, issue multiple commands): Get-ChildItem -Path '\\?\c:\1\info.txt' -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern 'tt3305316' -SimpleMatch | Select -first 1

Comment: The beauty of `findstr` is its `/G` switch to search for many search patterns without re-reading the file to search for each pattern. I'm not aware of a possibility to do the same in Powershell (I might be wrong, my Powershell skills are *very* basic). Does the `type ... | findstr ...` approach work?

Comment: type..... > The system cannot find the file specified - there are many info.txt in may sub-folders of main folder. PowerShell has multiple matches, I just dont know (yet) how it works.

Comment: `Select-String -Pattern 'first','second','third pattern','fourth'`, but you've got 8000... (you will hit the max line length limit with them)

Comment: Yes, multiple patterns, I was testing that right now. I can run multiple commands, either simultaneously or one after the other. Or maybe use an array?? Thank you for your help!

Comment: "*Faster / fastest way to* ..." Unanswerable without sample data.